# R ts with missing values

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame I read from a csv file that has daily observations:

```
Date        Value 
2010-01-04  23.4
2010-01-05  12.7
2010-01-04  20.1
2010-01-07  18.2
```

PROBLEM: Missing data.
Forecast package expects a plain `ts` object not containing any missing data, while my dataset has missing data on most weekends and other random points.

converting to `ts` should not work

```
ts(values, start = c(1997, 1), frequency = 1)
```

the only solution I can think of is to transform daily data to weekly data but R is a new thing and other better solutions could exist.

Comment: This is really a statistical question (how to handle missing values in time series) and you haven't given enough information yet (ratio of missing to present values and lengths of runs of missing). Voting to migrate to CrossValidated.com so you can then do some of your own searching before coming back with a fully articulated coding question.

Comment: Many functions in the forecast package allow for missing values.

Comment: @BondedDust it's more like how to perform required procedures to handle missing data using R

Answer (score 7):

One option is to expand your date index to include the missing observations, and use `na.approx` from `zoo` to fill in the missing values via interpolation.

```
allDates <- seq.Date(
  min(values$Date),
  max(values$Date),
  "day")
##
allValues <- merge(
  x=data.frame(Date=allDates),
  y=values,
  all.x=TRUE)
R> head(allValues,7)
        Date      Value
1 2010-01-05 -0.6041787
2 2010-01-06  0.2274668
3 2010-01-07 -1.2751761
4 2010-01-08 -0.8696818
5 2010-01-09         NA
6 2010-01-10         NA
7 2010-01-11 -0.3486378
##
zooValues <- zoo(allValues$Value,allValues$Date)
R> head(zooValues,7)
2010-01-05 2010-01-06 2010-01-07 2010-01-08 2010-01-09 2010-01-10 2010-01-11 
-0.6041787  0.2274668 -1.2751761 -0.8696818         NA         NA -0.3486378 
##
approxValues <- na.approx(zooValues)
R> head(approxValues,7)
2010-01-05 2010-01-06 2010-01-07 2010-01-08 2010-01-09 2010-01-10 2010-01-11 
-0.6041787  0.2274668 -1.2751761 -0.8696818 -0.6960005 -0.5223192 -0.3486378
```

Even with missing values, `zooValues` is still a legitimate `zoo` object, e.g. `plot(zooValues)` will work (with discontinuities at missing values), but if you plan on fitting some sort of model to the data, you will most likely be better off using `na.approx` to replace the missing values.

**Data:**

```
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
##
t0 <- "2010-01-04"
Dates <- as.Date(ymd(t0))+1:120
weekDays <- Dates[!(weekdays(Dates) %in% c("Saturday","Sunday"))]
##
set.seed(123)
values <- data.frame(Date=weekDays,Value=rnorm(length(weekDays)))
```

Comment: Thx I'm going to follow your indications

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **imputeTS**, **zoo** or **forecast** package, which all offer methods to fill the missing data.
(the process of filling missing gaps is also called imputation)

**imputeTS**

```
na_interpolation(yourData)
na_seadec(yourdata)
na_kalman(yourdata)
na_ma(yourdata)
```

**zoo**

```
na.approx(yourdata)
na.locf(yourdata)
na.StructTS(yourdata)
```

**forecast**

```
na.interp(yourdata)
```

These are some functions from the packages you could use.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to aggregate, yes - the important thing is to be smart about doing so. If you simply aggregate to week-level, using something like `lubridate` to map timestamps to weeks, you'll certainly end up with something that Forecast can consume - but it will be something with deceptive data, since some weeks will have smaller counts because they're missing days. This makes the dataset less useful for predictive modelling, because you're not giving it a model of what actually happened.

My recommendation would be to look at the zoo time series package for handling this; it has a lot of functions for working out the probable value of a missing/NA entry, based on the other data it's handed. Install it and run:

```
library(zoo)
ls(pattern = "^na", "package:zoo")
```

To get a list of functions you might find particularly relevant.

Comment: thx I dig into zoo package; do you have sources you can suggest to kickstart me?

Comment: The vignettes at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution form {padr}:

**Explicit interval**

```
require(padr)
require(magrittr)
df <- data.frame(day = as.Date(c('2016-04-01', '2016-04-03')), y = c(3,4))
pad(df, interval = "day") %>% fill_by_value(y)
#>          day y
#> 1 2016-04-01 3
#> 2 2016-04-02 0
#> 3 2016-04-03 4
```

**Inferred interval**

```
df <- data.frame(day = as.Date(c('2016-04-01', '2016-04-02', '2016-04-04')), y = c(3,4,6))
pad(df) %>% fill_by_value(y)
#> pad applied on the interval: day
#>          day y
#> 1 2016-04-01 3
#> 2 2016-04-02 4
#> 3 2016-04-03 0
#> 4 2016-04-04 6
```