# How to remove specific day data while forecasting in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to remove specific day but not sure how to do that.
Example R code can remove weekend data.

```
X <- seq(as.Date("2/1/2017", format="%m/%d/%Y"), 
         as.Date("5/18/2017", format="%m/%d/%Y"),"days")

weekdays.X <- X[ ! weekdays(X) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday") ]
```

But if i want any specific date data to be removed ,like 25th May 2017, than how to do that?

Thanks for your help.
Even you can provide link where i can find the solution.

Comment: `X[X != as.Date("2017-05-25")]`, although you don't have the 25th of May in your data...

Comment: thanks a lot,so if we remove any specific data than while forecasting its take average for that missing date?

Comment: That depends on what kind of algorithm you use for forecasting.

Comment: I'm no expert in forecasting, but you could take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368195/r-ts-with-missing-values) question.

Comment: I am using ts function for pulling data and using Arima function for forecasting. As i am using 5 days of data hence set frequency as 5.
data <-ts(data,start=c(2016,1),frequency=5)
suppose if i have holidays like show below

Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thrusday Friday
26 45 64 45 34
holiday 43 66 67 55
56 55 holiday 56 76
67 43 22 33 44

Comment: If you need help for dealing with missing data using `ts` or any other function, than post a new question stating your problem clearly.