# Daily Time Series Analysis

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a daily time series about the sales of a product, my series start from 01/01/2016 until 31/08/2017, my problem is that I do not know what value of frequency I should use, considering that it is a six-day week (my week starts on Monday and ends Saturday) and there is no data for Sundays.

Should be it like this ?

```
myts <- ts(sales, start=c(2016, 1), frequency=6)
```

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ts`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ts.html) expects you to have values for each element of the time-series, i.e., it would expect you to have the seventh day values in the data.

One option is to expand the date index to include your missing observations. You could fill those missing observations with `na.approx` or `na`, but you can't give `ts` a six day week and expect it to comprehend it as a seven day cycle.

A good way to do this is to look at `zoo`, which has specific functions for dealing with these sorts of situations.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your answer

Comment: NPs. if you need help filling in the missing values, search on zoo or post another question. Also, to close this question out, if you understand the result you could accept this answer by checking it and that will mark it as closed.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your answer !
Could You please, give me more information about how to do what You said ??, I'm still learning R and I do not know how to do it, or where I could find more information about it.

Comment: There are many different ways to get to that end goal of having 7 days of values for each week's observations. It depends on how you want to fill in those values. It also depends on what `sales` is as an object, etc. We don't have enough information to judge that in this question. You should close out this question and open a new question on how to fill in the missing values in your `sales` object, including what you want to fill in with, i.e., an interpolated value or just a straight `na`. Also, you will need to give some sample rows from `sales` to get people to be able to help. It's a new ?

Comment: Here is just one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368195/r-ts-with-missing-values

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do with the data.

**1) plot** for example, if your objective is simply to plot it then `"ts"` class is not a good fit since it is not good at representing dates.  Try this instead where we have defined test vector for `sales` and `tt` in the Note at the end.

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(sales, tt)
plot(z)
```

**2) acf** If you want to compute the autocorrelation function then using the plain vector `sales` or `ts(sales)` would be fine:

```
acf(sales)
```

**3) StructTS** If you want to fit a structural time series using `StructTS` then you will need to decide on the length of a cycle, i.e. does it repeat every week? quarter? year?.  Typically an annual cycle is appropriate for sales but, in general, you will need two complete cycles to do anything so you don't really have enough data for that.

**4) monthly/quarterly** If you are willing to reduce it to monthly or quarterly data then you could use `ts` but you only have 20 points for monthly or 7 for quarterly. Here we have used the last point in each month:

```
library(zoo)

z <- zoo(sales, tt)
zm <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, tail, 1) 
tsm <- as.ts(zm)
tsm
```

giving:

```
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug
2016 3.258097 3.931826 4.356709 4.644391 4.867534 5.049856 5.204007 5.342334
2017 5.828946 5.897154 5.968708 6.030685 6.093570 6.150603 6.204558 6.257668
          Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2016 5.459586 5.564520 5.659482 5.749393
2017
```

**5) weekly** Another thing you could consider would be to use weekly series by just using Saturday, for example:

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(sales, tt)
zw <- z[weekdays(time(z)) == "Saturday"]
```

**Note:** We used this dummy data:

```
set.seed(123)
tt <- seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2017-08-31"), "day")
tt <- tt[! weekdays(tt) == "Sunday"]
n <- length(tt)
sales <- log(1:n)
```